# DAX - Max of each day in calculated column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have data like in column `Date` and `Amount` and I am looking for DAX code to generate column `MacOfDay` (max of `Amount` for each day)

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following calculated column:

```
MaxOfDay = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX('Data'[Amount]),
    FILTER(
        'Data',
        'Data'[Date] = EARLIER('Data'[Date])
    )
)
```

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: @irrmat You're welcome. If my answer solved your issue please mark it as the correct answer as shown [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/313506) to positively close the question.